# Why was I called 君？

Tags: pronouns, second-person-pronouns

I’m talking with someone on Tandem who I’ve never spoken to before and he immediately called me 君. He’s only 2 years older than me and I thought きみ was for relationships where there is a bigger age difference/status difference or also very closely between friends or lovers and in songs/anime.

Is it just a personal choice or is there a specific reason?

Comment: Either his personal choice or you gave him an impression that you are what you said, I guess...